# Change to elipses when setting PROMPT_DIRTRIM

Tags: bash, ps1

PROMPT_DIRTRIM uses `...` to denote truncated paths. I'd like to change the symbol to the ellipses character `…`

Comment: You need to change the source code, and recompile it.

Comment: I guess someone should just open a PR to fix this and add something like PROMPT_DIRTRIM_SYMBOL